# Pandas dataframe groupby top N items

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'item_code': ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item1', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item2', 'Item1', 'Item3'],
        'dollar_amount': ['200.25', '350.00', '120.00', '400.50', '1001.25', '700.00', '350.00', '200.25', '240.00'],
        'supplier_code': ['Sup1','Sup1','Sup2','Sup1','Sup1','Sup1','Sup1','Sup2','Sup2']})
```

This is how this dataframe looks:

```
    dollar_amount  item_code     supplier_code
0   200.25         Item1         Sup1
1   350.00         Item2         Sup1
2   120.00         Item3         Sup2
3   400.50         Item1         Sup1
4   1001.25        Item1         Sup1
5   700.00         Item2         Sup1
6   350.00         Item2         Sup1
7   200.25         Item1         Sup2
8   240.00         Item3         Sup2
```

I can get the top N Items summed up by `dollar_amount` with this:

```
a = data.groupby('item_code', as_index=False).sum()
cnt_srs = a[['item_code','dollar_amount']].sort_values(by=['dollar_amount'], ascending=False).head(15)
cnt_srs
```

Sample output top-5 items (not of the above data):

```
        item_code   dollar_amount
 173    Item1       8,776,906.5400
 442    Item2       2,085,528.8170
 367    Item3       2,033,746.0500
 25     Item4       1,635,830.4040
 537    Item5       1,485,672.4050
```

Now I want the `supplier_code`s for these items.

I can get the supplier_code and its most frequently supplied item using this:

```
N = 1
df1 = data.groupby(['supplier_code'])['item_code'].value_counts().groupby('supplier_code').head(N)
df1
```

Sample Output:

```
supplier_code  item_code
Sup1           Item4      9
Sup2           Item2      21
Sup3           Item1      7
Sup4           Item5      173
Sup5           Item3      1
Sup6           Item6      12
```

**I want to get the top N Item and their Supplier where top N items are determined by the sum of their dollar amounts.**

**Expected Output:**

```
item_code      dollar_amount     SupplierCode
TopItem1       8,776,906.5400    Sup4
TopItem2       2,085,528.8170    Sup1
TopItem3       2,033,746.0500    Sup3
TopItem4       1,635,830.4040    Sup1
TopItem5       1,485,672.4050    Sup2
```

I want the top N Items(In terms of dollar_amount) and the corresponding Supplier_codes

Thank you so much for all the help up till now.

Comment: I'm unable to understand what you want. Which one of it is the expected output

Comment: @Dark I'll edit the question

Comment: Does item can have multiple supplier codes?

Comment: @user8505495 yes. But only the top supplier would be enough

Comment: Can you please fix up the code? First you show us one dataframe, then you show us "Sample output top-5 items (not of the above data)" from a different dataframe with an unexplained row-index ( `supplier_code`? or delete the row-index if irrelevant). Which are we dealing with? Can you give these names like `df1, df2, df_top5,...` or whatever?

Comment: Also, pandas `nlargest()` probably does what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('item_code', as_index=False)
         .agg({'dollar_amount':'sum', 'supplier_code': 'first'}))
print (df1)
  item_code supplier_code  dollar_amount
0     Item1          Sup1        1802.25
1     Item2          Sup1        1400.00
2     Item3          Sup2         360.00
```

Comment: Each Item has a SupplierCode. And I want the top N Items and their SupplierCodes. The way I am deciding for the top N items is by summing up each item's DollarAmount.

Comment: Since each Item has atleast one Supplier the column 'a' cant have a NaN. It must have a SupplierCode for that Item.

Comment: Hmmm, i see problem in `Sample Output:` - is guaranteed unique `item_code`? If not how it match? I get NaN because working with your sample data.

Comment: Are you sure the second element is NaN? I thought it should be Sup1.

Comment: @jezrael Its just a Sample Output. It doesn't represent the data

Comment: @EL323 - I change answer, how does it work with real data?

Comment: @jezrael Is there a way I can send you the data?

Comment: @EL323 Yes, you can send them to my email in my profile.

Comment: @jezrael I have sent you the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample data and if you only want the first supplier_code, then below will suffice.

```
>>> print(df.groupby('item_code').agg({'dollar_amount':sum, 'supplier_code': lambda curr: curr.iloc[0]}).sort_values('dollar_amount', ascending=False).reset_index())
  item_code  dollar_amount supplier_code
0     Item1        1802.25          Sup1
1     Item2        1400.00          Sup1
2     Item3         360.00          Sup2
```

reset_index() is optional. I just used it to return a DataFrame.

But if you need to get the top supplier_code per item_code then I think you need to do a dual group_by.

```
>>> print(df.groupby(['item_code', 'supplier_code']).sum().sort_values('dollar_amount', ascending=False).reset_index().groupby('item_code').agg({'dollar_amount':sum, 'supplier_code': lambda curr: curr.iloc[0]}).reset_index())
  item_code  dollar_amount supplier_code
0     Item1        1802.25          Sup1
1     Item2        1400.00          Sup1
2     Item3         360.00          Sup2
```